# Problema com chamada de função no CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

Tenho isso na model Passagem.php:

```
<?php
class Passagem extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Passagem';
}?>
```

E isso em PassagensController.php:

```
<?php
class PassagensController extends AppController {
    public $helpers = array('Html','Form');
    public $name = 'Passagens';
    public $components = array('Session');

    function index(){
        $this->set('passagens', $this->Passagem->find('all'));
    }
}?>
```

No momento em que eu acesso a página Passagens, acontece um erro com essa descrição:

> "Error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object
>   File: C:\wamp\www\VendaDePassagens\app\Controller\PassagensController.php
>   Line: 8"

Obs: No projeto existem outros Models e Controllers. Mas, somente em "Passagens" ocorre esse erro.

O que pode ser?

Answer (score 3):

Tente o seguinte:

No seu PassagensController adicione o $uses conforme abaixo:

```
<?php
class PassagensController extends AppController {
   public $helpers = array('Html','Form');
   public $name = 'Passagens';
   public $components = array('Session');
   public $uses = array('Passagem');

   function index(){
      $this->set('passagens', $this->Passagem->find('all'));
   }

}?>
```

Comment: Isso deve mesmo resolver. Acho que o problema é quero cake não sabe que o singular de passagens é passagem.

Comment: Exatamente, se fosse Passage creio que ele funcionaria automaticamente, porém como você usou o Pt-BR ele não consegue identificar.

Comment: Fiz isso...Olha o que ocorre:

Error: Table passagems for model Passagem was not found in datasource default.

Muito estranho aquele "passagems" !!!

Comment: @Tercio O motivo é o mesmo. Ou você adiciona um `public $useTable = 'passagem';` no model, ou cria uma nova regra de [inflection](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html#inflection-configuration) para ensinar o cake a converter singular/plural direito.

Comment: Concordo com o @bfavaretto. É tudo questão de singular/plural que a regra de inflection do cake não interpreta em português.

Comment: Consertado!!! Agradeço a todos!!! Coloquei o inflections.php e deu tudo certo!

Answer (score 1):

Não entendo muito de cakephp, mas, pelo que li no site, diz que se deve usar o seguinte:

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
```

antes da definição da classe, ficaria assim sua model Passagem.php:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class Passagem extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Passagem';
}?>
```

Modifique seu código da PassagensController.php para:

```
<?php
class PassagensController extends AppController {
    public $helpers = array('Html','Form');
    public $name = 'Passagens';
    public $components = array('Session');

    function index(){
        $this->loadModel('Passagem');
        $this->set('passagens', $this->Passagem->find('all'));
    }
}?>
```

O problema é que você está tentando chamar a função de um módulo não carregado.
Fonte: [Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11474447/error-call-to-a-member-function-find-on-a-non-object-in-cakephp-controller)

Comment: O problema é que o erro só acontece neste Controller. Nos outros não ocorre este erro.

Comment: Não é isso pois deveria reconhecer diretamente já que o esse controller pertence ao modulo.

Comment: Esse está seguindo as normas normais do cakePhp. Como a nomenclatura das classes estão corretas (se estiver usando o pluguin 'CakePtbr') então o model seria carregado automáticamente.

Answer (score 0):

#### Solução

Faltou adicionar

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
```

Ao inicio do Model, ficaria assim:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class Passagem extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Passagem';
}
?>
```

#### Motivo

App::uses('AppModel', 'Model') garante que o Model será carregado (lazy load) em cada instancia em que for chamada.

#### Erro da Descricao

Como a propriedade Passagem nao estava definida (nao relacionada ao Model), o uso de um método em uma propriedade que nao é por sí um objeto, causa tal erro

Comment: O problema é que o erro só acontece neste Controller. Nos outros não ocorre este erro.
Tentei usar este método que você falou. Não obtive sucesso.

Comment: pode ser que somente nesse, nao esteja carregado como citado na resposta, tente usar outro nome na classe, para ver se o erro persiste.

Comment: Coloquei outro nome na classe. Sem sucesso.